# installing passenger rack error

Tags: ruby, passenger

When I am installing the passenger rack I am getting the following error

I have upgraded to the version 1.9.3 as shown below

any suggestion

```
 [centos@ip-10-1-213-37 puppet]$ sudo gem install passenger
    ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
            rake requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
    [centos@ip-10-1-213-37 puppet]$ ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: How is ruby installed?

Answer (score 0):

You call `ruby -v` as regular user, and `sudo gem install passenger` as root. I suggest you to upgrade your ruby version; you could use [rvm](http://rvm.io) for this purpose.